# Keep transparency with basemap warpimage

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I have an RGBA png map with all oceans transparent.

[image]

I want to use Basemap in a north pole stereographic projection and this map with warpimage. The transparency is lost and replaced by black when I want to keep it. What can i do ? 
My final goal is to plot a color grid in oceans and then the transparent map above it.

[image]

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=60,lon_0=300,resolution='l',round=True)
m.drawlsmask(ocean_color='white')
m.warpimage("land.png")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug in function `warpimage`. If the projection is not cylindrical the original image has to be transformed and this is the place where transparency is lost. Namely, in file `mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py` in function `warpimage`:

```
1> 4141                 for k in range(3):
   4142                     self._bm_rgba_warped[:,:,k],x,y = \
   4143                     self.transform_scalar(self._bm_rgba[:,:,k],\
   4144                     self._bm_lons,self._bm_lats,nx,ny,returnxy=True)
```

Here, RGB channels (for k=0,1,2) from the original file (`self._bm_rgba`) are transformed and passed to the warped image but the alpha channel (with index `k = 3`) is not.

### Solution

If you can modify your python distribution,
locate file `mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py`, find a function `warpimage` and change line `for k in range(3):` (around line 4141 as in the code above) to

```
for k in range(self._bm_rgba.shape[2]):
```

This fixes the problem.

Line numbers may differ. I use basemap-1.0.7.

---

By the way, I used your jpg file for testing and noticed it didn't have the alpha channel. I hope you are aware of it.

### Update

Actually, this bug was already [fixed](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/pull/217) in the github version of [basemap](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap).

Comment: Ah it's true, the image I loaded lost transparency. Anyway your solution works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Great, glad I could help. I've just learned, somewhat belatedly, two things. The bug has already been fixed in the latest basemap version on github. (Apparently, it can't be installed with pip. My pip tries to convince me that version 1.0.7 is up to date.) And the other thing: jpeg files don't support transparency :)