# Matplotlib Basemap example code fails due to MemoryError

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to use the Basemap toolkit from matplotlib to plot data on a map. When I try to run the following code

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# setup Lambert Conformal basemap.
# set resolution=None to skip processing of boundary datasets.
m = Basemap(width=12000000,height=9000000,projection='lcc',
            resolution=None,lat_1=45.,lat_2=55,lat_0=50,lon_0=-107.)
m.shadedrelief()
plt.show()
```

which is copied and pasted directly from [example #4 on the basemap tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/geography.html)

The code fails with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basemap_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    m.shadedrelief()
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 4043, in shadedrelief
    return self.warpimage(image='shadedrelief',scale=scale,**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 4171, in warpimage
    self._bm_rgba = self._bm_rgba.astype(np.float32)/255.
MemoryError
```

I am running Python 3.5.1 using matplotlib version 1.5.1 and Basemap version 1.0.8

I have found a couple threads ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885953/keep-transparency-with-basemap-warpimage/36963029#36963029) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243506/python-basemap-error-using-shadedrelief-bluemarble-or-etopo-false-longitude-f)) that deal with similar bugs in mpl_toolkits/basemap/**init**.py that have supposedly been fixed but none that address this problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your code works fine on my laptop --- I have 8GB of RAM...

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by upgrading to 64-bit python. It seems that even though Basemap publishes a version for 32-bit python not all the map functions work in 32-bit, even the standard examples.